# I want to install Angular 6 instead of instead of Angular 8. How can i do?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I installed Node JS latest version. After that i installed Angular-CLI and created angular sample application with ng new command. Its created Angular 8 application. I have to install angular 6 instead of instead of Angular 8. How can i do?

Comment: Why would you do that? Do you have an incompatibility?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new folder then use the below command to create a new project

```
npm i @angular/cli@6
ng new my-ng6-app
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command,

npm install @angular/cli@**version**

```
npm install @angular/cli@6.2.6
```